# What GSON deserializers do I need?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

Evening,

I retrieve JSON data from a server in this format:

Json-Book:

```
{
    _id: String,
    isbn: String,
    owner: String username,
    rentedTo: Array[String usernames]
}
```

Json-Crowd:

```
{
    _id: String,
    isbn: String,
    owner: String username,
    availableForRent: Integer, 
    rentedTo: Array[String usernames]
}
```

Json-User:

```
{
    username: String,
    books: Array[Book],
    crowds: Array[Crowd]
}
```

Similarly, I have three classes:

```
public class Book{
    private String _id;
    private String isbn;
    private User owner;
    private ArrayList<User> rentedTo;

    public Book(String _id, String isbn, User owner, ArrayList<User> rentedTo) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.rentedTo = rentedTo;
    }
}

public class Crowd {
    private String _id;
    private String name;
    private User owner;
    private ArrayList<User> members;

    public Crowd(String _id, String name, User owner, ArrayList<User> members) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.members = members;
    }
}
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Shelf shelf;
    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    private ArrayList<Crowd> crowds;

    public User(String name, ArrayList<Book> books, ArrayList<Crowd> crowds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.booksOwned = books;
        this.crowds = crowds;
    }
}
```

As you can see, all the field names match up, but not all of the types. Users in the keys `owner` and `rentedTo` in Json-book and Json-crowd have values of type `String` and `ArrayList<String>` respectively, where the strings are unique usernames. In the classes, these fields are of type `User` and `ArrayList<User>`. In and of itself, this is no problem, because I can get the User object from the string with this method:

```
    public User getUser(String username) {
        return users.get(username);
    }
```

Now, I'm a bit confused as to what deserializers I need in order to get proper objects from the JSON data. How would the, uh, architecture of this look? Deserializers for each class `Book`, `Crowd` and `User`, each of which fetches one field at a time from the Json-data and calls the constructor?
I can't wrap my head around how this would work together. The deserializer for `User` would need to use/reference the deserializer for `Crowd`, but do I another deserializer since the objects are in array?

I assume I would need an opposite set of serializers in order to get the classes into Json-data of the correct format.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question: If in the JSON the `owner` is just a String containing the username, how are you going to create a whole `User` Object from that? Are you planning on doing separate request to get the remaining user data? Does your response a big chunk of JSON that contains all the books and users? I think Gson works works best if you only use it to transform a JSON tree to an object graph that looks more or less the same - serializers and deserializers mostly change the details of parsing a subtree, but cannot (easily?) get data from some whole other place...

Comment: The plan was to have a hashmap with `User` Objects and username as key, and if I can't find it there, then I will to a separate request to get the remaining data. Now, I realize that this will just recursively get more and more data from the server until it reaches a dead end, but lets ignore that. The question above is still valid, just assume that I have magic functions that will return a full `User` object given the username if I need to parse JSON-data that only contains username(s).